# In Rubymine, Rails fails to load 'uglifier' gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, rubymine

I have an issue while running *Rails* from *Rubymine* where it fails to load the **uglifier** gem with the stack below. Note that *Node.js* is installed on my *Windows 7* computer.

From *cmd.exe*, 'rails s' works well : the web application starts.

From *RubyMine* run button, default configuration, I get the error :

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\RubyMine 8.0.2\bin\runnerw.exe" C:\tools\languages\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.2.0\bin\ruby.exe -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) C:/projects/perso/exercises/bin/rails server -b 127.0.0.1 -p 3000 -e development
C:/tools/languages/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:80:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'uglifier'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
    from C:/tools/languages/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from C:/tools/languages/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from C:/tools/languages/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from C:/tools/languages/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from C:/tools/languages/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from C:/tools/languages/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `require'
    from C:/projects/perso/exercises/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/tools/languages/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
    from C:/tools/languages/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
    from C:/tools/languages/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from C:/tools/languages/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from C:/tools/languages/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from C:/tools/languages/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/projects/perso/exercises/bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from C:/projects/perso/exercises/bin/rails:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
Process finished with exit code 1
```

I get the same error from *RubyMine* terminal.

Here's some information on my environment from (same output from *cmd.exe* and *RubyMine*) :

```
>rails --version
Rails 4.2.6
>node --version
v0.10.22
>ruby --version
ruby 2.2.4p230 (2015-12-16 revision 53155) [i386-mingw32]
```

*Ruby* was installed using *Rails Installer* on a *Windows 7* computer.
*Node.js* is installed too, using official installer.
*RubyMine 8.0.4* (ultimate, not sure if there's a community version too)

I suspect an environment problem inside *RubyMine* in which *rails*/*bundler*/*gem*/? can't "see" *Node.js*, where *cmd.exe* can.

I think the error started when I tryed to start *RubyMine* debug mode.

Any idea on how to solve the issue ?

Thanks

Edit : some more information

My *Gemfile* :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


gem 'rails', '4.2.6'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

*rake tasks* (for example to get the full error stack, note the `ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable: Could not find a JavaScript runtime.` )

```
>rake tasks --trace
rake aborted!
Bundler::GemRequireError: There was an error while trying to load the gem 'uglifier'.
C:/tools/languages/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:80:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require'
C:/tools/languages/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
C:/tools/languages/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
C:/tools/languages/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
C:/tools/languages/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
C:/tools/languages/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
C:/tools/languages/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `require'
C:/projects/perso/exercises/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
C:/tools/languages/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
C:/tools/languages/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
C:/projects/perso/exercises/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
C:/tools/languages/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
C:/tools/languages/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
C:/tools/languages/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:689:in `raw_load_rakefile'
C:/tools/languages/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
C:/tools/languages/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/tools/languages/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
C:/tools/languages/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
C:/tools/languages/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/tools/languages/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
C:/tools/languages/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
C:/tools/languages/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
C:/tools/languages/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable: Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/rails/execjs for a list of available runtimes.
C:/tools/languages/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/execjs-2.6.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:48:in `autodetect'
C:/tools/languages/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/execjs-2.6.0/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
C:/tools/languages/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/execjs-2.6.0/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
C:/tools/languages/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/uglifier-3.0.0/lib/uglifier.rb:5:in `require'
C:/tools/languages/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/uglifier-3.0.0/lib/uglifier.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
C:/tools/languages/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `require'
C:/tools/languages/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in require'
C:/tools/languages/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
C:/tools/languages/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
C:/tools/languages/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
C:/tools/languages/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
C:/tools/languages/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `require'
C:/projects/perso/exercises/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
C:/tools/languages/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
C:/tools/languages/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
C:/projects/perso/exercises/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
C:/tools/languages/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
C:/tools/languages/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
C:/tools/languages/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:689:in `raw_load_rakefile'
C:/tools/languages/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
C:/tools/languages/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/tools/languages/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
C:/tools/languages/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
C:/tools/languages/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/tools/languages/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
C:/tools/languages/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
C:/tools/languages/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
C:/tools/languages/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working, here's the context and solution if someone else has the same issue.

I have defined a user scoped *Path* variable which was refering to my system *Path* as :

```
%Path%;C:\tools\…
```

In RedMine, this `%Path%` was not interpreted anymore (don't know why). I saw it by typing in *RubyMine* Terminal :

```
echo %Path%
```

The result was displaying "`%Path%`", not its content.

I solved the problem by simply **rebooting** the computer.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, though my solution isn't that simple!

I have a run configuration that has field "Environment variables" set with `PATH=d:\opt\curl-7.40.0-devel-mingw64\bin\;%PATH%;=`. But when I click on "..." right to this field, in value column it says `d:\opt\curl-7.40.0-devel-mingw64\bin\;%PATH%" (without the "=" at the end)`.

I changed it so that it includes the path to `node.exe`

`PATH=d:\opt\curl-7.40.0-devel-mingw64\bin\;d:\opt\nodejs\;%PATH%;`

Now it works fine.

I run ruby 2.2.3-x64 with Rails 4.2.5 on a Windows 10 machine.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your Gemfile has the following gem

```
gem 'uglifier'
```

If you already have the gem in Gemfile, then run bundle install and check if the bundle in installing the uglifier gem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added my Gemfile to the original post. I already have the uglifier gem and it is installed normally but it fails to load it when I lanch rails or rake.